# Rewrite rule to exclude static files, like woff and tff

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, httpd.conf

I would like to avoid applying URL rewrite rules to font files like `woff` and `tff`. I tried the following:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\.(jpg|css|js|gif|png|woff|tff)$ [NC]`

But it didnt work.

My font file location is `/theme/fonts`. But I would like to do it based on extension, in case the location changes later on.

What would be the correct condition so that *.woff files are not applied any rewrite rules?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change you negation based condition to this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\.(jpe?g|css|js|gif|png|woff|tff)\s [NC]
```

Using `THE_REQUEST` variable instead of `REQUEST_URI` because other rules may impact `REQUEST_URI` unlike `THE_REQUEST`.